# Inner join 3 tables for permission

Tags: mysql, sql

Hey all i am trying to populate my query with all the records in table user and have each one check to see their permissions from 2 other tables (user_permission & permission).

The current query i have is this:

```
SELECT user.id, user.email,  
CONCAT(' ', user.name, user.username) AS theNameUserName,
IF(user.opted_in = 0, 'NO', 'YES') AS optedIn  
FROM user AS user, user_permission AS userPerm
INNER JOIN permission AS Perm ON Perm.id = userPerm.permission_id;
```

Which executes without a problem but has only the same data over and over again. It only has **1000 records returned and its duplicating each person 3 times**. I have **470 user(s)** in the **user table** so i should return **all 470 records** that also tell me their permission.

What do i need to do to my query above in order for it to do that? **User.id** will match up with **user_permission user_id**.

user_permission table layout:

```
  user_id  permission_id
       1        1
       2        3
       3        3
       8        4
       9        4
      10        4
      11        4
      12        4
      13        4
       ....etc etc
```

permission table:

```
   id            name
    4      registered users
    3      editor
    2      developer
    1      administrator
    5      registered builders
```

user table:

```
   id      name         email                username           opted_in
   11   David Dxxxx     dxxxxx@exxxx.com    dxxxxxx@exxxxx.com      0
   12   Michael Lxx     sx@sprintmail.com   sxxxxxx@sxxxxx.com      0
   13   Jon Fxxxxxx     jxxxxxxx@xxx.com    jxxxxxx@sxxxxx.com      0
        etc etc .......
```

Comment: you shouldn't mix oldschool joins with ansi joins. stick with ansi joins only.

Comment: Why do you do `user as user`?

Comment: @arnoudhgz: Good question.. i dont know i just gave it a name like i did the other 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an unusual mix of implicit (comma-separated) `INNER JOIN`s and explicit ones, and ultimately you have no condition joining `user` to `user_permission` which is why you get a cartesian product of the two.  Your `JOIN`s should look like:

```
SELECT
  user.id,
  user.email,  
  CONCAT_WS(' ', user.name, user.username) AS theNameUserName,
  IF(user.opted_in = 0, 'NO', 'YES') AS optedIn  
FROM 
  user
  LEFT JOIN user_permission AS userPerm ON user.id = userPerm.user_id
  INNER JOIN permission AS Perm ON Perm.id = userPerm.permission_id;
```

I have substituted a `LEFT JOIN` between `user` and `user_permission` to list users having no related permissions as `NULL`. If they should be omitted from the result, use an `INNER JOIN` instead.

I also replaced your `CONCAT()` with `CONCAT_WS()` since you have the space first - you would have just been sticking a space onto the front of the string rather than separating the two (if that is what you intended).

A final note: your `IF()` condition in the `SELECT` works great for MySQL and a few other RDBMS, but the most portable version of that would use a `CASE` instead:

```
CASE WHEN user.opted_in = 0 THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END AS theNameUserName
```

... just a suggestion if you ever expect to need to run this on a different RDBMS.